# Make the image in content of the ::before selector stretch to the screen

Tags: css

I have the following CSS code:

```
div#bodyContainer:before {
  content: url(/image/colorbar.png);
  width: 100%;
  display: block;  
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="bodyContainer">
        In post mean shot ye. There out her child sir his lived. Design at uneasy me season of branch on praise esteem. Abilities discourse believing consisted remaining to no. Mistaken no me denoting dashwood as screened. Whence or esteem easily he on. Dissuade husbands at of no if disposal.     
    </div>
</body>
```

The width of the image (colorbar.png) is smaller than the screen's width. I hope to make the image stretch (but not repeat) to the entire screen horizontally, but the above code is not working. Is this doable? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: add your html also

Comment: Updated with the HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) property instead.

```
div#bodyContainer:before {
  background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/mountain.jpg);/*background*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;/*do not repeat background*/
  background-size: cover;/*cover entire element by stretching it*/
  display: block;/*block elements take up entire width*/
  content: '';/*pseudo element requires content*/
  height: 100px;/*must set explicit height*/
}
```

```css
div#bodyContainer:before {
  background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/mountain.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 100px;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="bodyContainer">
        In post mean shot ye. There out her child sir his lived. Design at uneasy me season of branch on praise esteem. Abilities discourse believing consisted remaining to no. Mistaken no me denoting dashwood as screened. Whence or esteem easily he on. Dissuade husbands at of no if disposal.     
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tested it out too on my machine. A perfect workaround. Genius!

Comment: @curious1 Happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

Per [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/content/#image) you cannot resize images inserted this way.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Googled it but failed to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. Although you have to specify a height, or use the padding aspect ratio trick.

Then just get your image in as a background image.

```css
div#bodyContainer::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url('/image/colorbar.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: I tested your code, but didn't work fully. The answer works like a charm. Thanks for your help. Repped.